# C OR '|' operator

Tags: c, assignment-operator, bitwise-or

I have an statement in a C program by someone else in this format
`int variable |= functioncall(parameter);`
I don't understand the use of OR '|' sign in that statement. Can any one please explain what does it do with the assignment operator. I am guessing bitwise OR and then assign.

Comment: Your guess is correct. C have many assignment operators like this, like `+=` or `*=`.

Comment: Have you tried a [basic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_assignment_operators)?

Comment: `a |= b` same as `a = a | b` Google is your friend

Comment: I tried searching it but couldn't find it. That is the reason I posted it here.

Answer (score 2):

`|=` is the bitwise OR assignment operator. Basically, `a |= b` means `a = a | b`.

Please check [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators) for a list of all such compound assignment operators.

For here, the exact meaning of the whole statement `someVar |= functioncall(parameter);` is:

1. Compute the return value of `functioncall(parameter)` and then,
2. Do bitwise OR on the return value and the original value of `someVar`,
3. And finally assign the result of the bitwise OR to `someVar`.

Comment: In C, it cannot be overloaded.

Comment: @immibis oops. Removed that paragraph since custom operator overloading is not supported in C.