# How does bit shift reverse this unsigned short int

Tags: bit-manipulation, reverse

I'm confused about this bitwise operation including the symbol `|` and how the shift left and shift right work in this example of code to reverse the int below:

```
uint16_t swap_uint16( uint16_t val ) 
{
    return (val << 8) | (val >> 8 );
}
```

So what I understand is the << shifts the int left and >> shifts it right. I'm not sure how the `|` works with these two shift operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: [C OR '|' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33536187/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the language but in most languages `|` means `bit-wise OR` so you are most likely looking at OR'ing each respective bit

```
example random bytes
A: 11001010
B: 00101011
-----------
   11101011  (A and B bit-wise OR'ed)
```